# Sequential update of Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

On page 1 of my spreadsheet I have a bunch of Google Finance functions to retrieve historical data of various scrips. On page 2 I have some calculations running based on the historical data and on page 3 I have lot more calculations being done based on the calculations on page 2.

Every time I open this document it takes considerable time to update all the three sheets because of the interlinking. Can I program a sequence in which the sheets auto update on first open? What I'm looking for is a delay to allow the Google Finance equations on page 1 be fist updated and then page 2 followed by page 3.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] . Short answer Yes by using an installable trigger and avoiding the use of custom functions. If you need further help please add more details.

Comment: @Rubén thanks for response, will try the trigger function and if I still have difficulties will reach out.

Comment: @Rubén "_Yes by using an installable trigger_" I struggled to think of a solution to this question, and I freely admit that I don't understand how a trigger could affect the recalculation order. Is this the kind of logic that you are applying [Recalculate google sheet on demand](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/129070/196152)?

Comment: @Tedinoz Let's focus on this question. I'm assuming that the OP is using custom functions, there is no way to prevent that custom functions be calculated when a spreadsheet is opened. Are you assuming the same and do you agree that custom functions always are calculated when the spreadsheet is opened?

Comment: @Rubén I **not** assuming that there are custom functions. OTOH, I have it on the highest authority ;) that [custom functions are recalculated on opening the spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116526/196152).