# Auto-Populate document name into cell in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to auto-populate the document's name into a single cell in sheets no matter if/when the doc name is changed. I can enter a formula from a script =DocName(), but it won't update when the document name is changed.

The script I used was

`function DocName() { return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName(); }`

I tried combining the =DocName() function with =IF(TODAY()=TODAY() but kept getting errors no matter how I formatted it.

Comment: Hi. _I tried combining the =DocName() function with =IF(TODAY()=TODAY()_ This won't work because  though [previous versions of Google Sheets Google Apps Script allowed the use of functions like NOW(), TODAY() and other deterministic built-in functions as custom function arguments, but nowadays they aren't allowed.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116526/196152)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make that a custom function update its result immediately](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/109054/how-to-make-that-a-custom-function-update-its-result-immediately)

Comment: Tedinoz unfortunately no it doesn't. That is referencing sheet names, not the entire document name. I'm looking for the document name to auto-populate as a header on each of the sheets within the document.

Comment: I don’t think you have read **and** understood the answer to that post. Whether it is the sheet name OR the document name is of no consequence because _neither will work in a custom function_. Why? Because something has to trigger it, and functions like NOW and TODAY don’t work in a custom function. You need to explore a work-around, and there are a few covered in Ruben’s answer. There are also many precedents on WebApps and StackOverflow for this kind of question, so some research there would be productive.

Comment: This was my first exploration of scripts, so you're right. I didn't understand what I was reading or if the answer I was looking for was there. I come here because I know there are others that know more than myself and humbly ask questions not knowing where to start research. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a script that worked [here](https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/10/28/automatic-recalculation-of-custom-function-on-spreadsheet-part-2/), where it forces the custom function I mentioned in my original post to run on open, updating the cell with the name of the document.

Comment: Indeed, a work around.